# Resize desktop icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

How do I resize the desktop icons in Windows 7? My 4 year old daughter decided to make them all REALLY big.

Comment: Daughter was being distracting...should be how

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also hold Ctrl, while you wheel the mouse wheel.

Which is probably how your 4 year old did it :)

Answer (score 4):

Right Click on Desktop -> View -> Medium Icons

(Unfortunately it doesn't put them back to the position they used to be, as I just found out).